# NextJs 9.4.4 + material UI + styled component project takes 15 seconds in avg to save changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styled-components, i18next

I had a project with Next 8 and custom node server.js file that handles routing it was good and fast but it didn't had a material ui
I added material ui and upgraded the project to Next 9.4.4 and removed the custom server.
but since I added material UI even on the old server it's very slow! I tried many solutions but non of them worked. changing routes takes up to 30 seconds! adding text and save takes 10~15 seconds! development mode is very slow. can you suggest me solutions?

_app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
import cookies from 'next-cookies';
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import NextSeo from 'next-seo';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ThemeProvider as StyledThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import withReduxSaga from 'next-redux-saga';
import { FlexContainer, theme as styledTheme } from '../config/globalStyles';
import materialTheme from '../config/theme';
import defaultSEOConfig from '../next-seo.config';
import createStore from '../config/store';
import { isCompatibleBrowser } from '../config/helpers';
import { appWithTranslation } from '../config/i18n';
import withGA from '../services/common/withGA';
import { getGAKey } from '../config/ga';
import Text from '../components/atoms/Text';
import { confirm } from '../config/confirm';
import { setCommonState } from '../redux/actions';
import InfoBar from '../components/molecules/InfoBar';
import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css';
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
import '../static/css/general.css';

Sentry.init({ dsn:"KEY" });

Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => {
  NProgress.start();
};

Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => NProgress.done();
Router.onRouteChangeError = () => NProgress.done();

const legalInformation = (
  <StyledThemeProvider theme={styledTheme}>
    legalInformation
  </StyledThemeProvider>
);

const acceptLegal = () => {
  document.cookie = `acceptedLegal=1; path=/; max-age=${86400 * 365}`;
};

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

    const { acceptedLegal, isAdminNavigation } = cookies(appContext.ctx);

    const userAgent = appContext.ctx.req
      ? appContext.ctx.req.headers['user-agent']
      : navigator.userAgent;
    const oldBrowser = !isCompatibleBrowser(userAgent);
    return { ...appProps, acceptedLegal, isAdminNavigation, oldBrowser };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { store, isAdminNavigation } = this.props;
    const isOpen = isAdminNavigation === 'true';
    store.dispatch(setCommonState('adminNavigation', isOpen, 'header'));
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    Sentry.withScope(scope => {
      Object.keys(errorInfo).forEach(key => {
        scope.setExtra(key, errorInfo[key]);
      });

      Sentry.captureException(error);
    });

    super.componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo);
  }

  renderCookieModal() {
    const { acceptedLegal } = this.props;
    if (!acceptedLegal && typeof document !== 'undefined')
      confirm({
        title: 'Cookies Policy',
        message: legalInformation,
        confirmLabel: 'I accept',
        cancelLabel: "I don't accept",
        onConfirm: acceptLegal,
        reactConfirmAlertOptions: {
          closeOnEscape: false,
          closeOnClickOutside: false,
        },
        closeOnCancel: false,
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store, oldBrowser } = this.props;

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.HubSpotConversations) {
      if (Router.router.route !== '/home') {
        if (window.HubSpotConversations.widget.status().loaded) {
          window.HubSpotConversations.widget.remove();
        }
      }
    }

    return (
      <StyledThemeProvider theme={styledTheme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={materialTheme}>
          <NextSeo config={defaultSEOConfig} />
          <Provider store={store}>
            <FlexContainer>
              <div>
                {oldBrowser && (
                  <InfoBar
                    content="You’re using an old or incompatible browser. Please use the latest version of Google Chrome or Firefox for an issue-free experience."
                    palette="warning"
                  />
                )}
              </div>
              <div>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              </div>
            </FlexContainer>
            <ToastContainer style={{ zIndex: 10001 }} />
            {this.renderCookieModal()}
          </Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StyledThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const gaApp = appWithTranslation(withGA(getGAKey(), false, Router)(MyApp));

export default withRedux(createStore)(withReduxSaga(gaApp))
```

_document.js

```
import React from 'react';
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet as StyledComponentSheets } from 'styled-components';
import { ServerStyleSheets as MaterialUiServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

class MyDocument extends Document {
 

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
          />
          <meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
          <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

          {this.props.styleTags}
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="57x57"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="60x60"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="72x72"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="76x76"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="114x114"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="120x120"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="144x144"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="152x152"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="180x180"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="192x192"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="32x32"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/favicon-32x32.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="96x96"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/favicon-96x96.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="16x16"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/favicon-16x16.png`}
          />
          <link
            rel="manifest"
            href={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/manifest.json`}
          />
          {/* <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" /> */}
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
          {/* <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:300,400,500,700&display=swap" /> */}

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#009ce1" />
          <meta
            name="msapplication-TileImage"
            content={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png`}
          />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#009ce1" />
          <script
            type="text/javascript"
            id="hs-script-loader"
            async
            defer
            src="//js.hs-scripts.com/5669472.js"
          />
          {/* <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" /> */}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const materialUiSheets = new MaterialUiServerStyleSheets();
  const styledComponentSheet = new StyledComponentSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  try {
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        // enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        enhanceApp: App => props =>
          styledComponentSheet.collectStyles(materialUiSheets.collect(<App {...props} />)),
        enhanceComponent: Component => Component,
      });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: (
        <React.Fragment>
          {initialProps.styles}
          {materialUiSheets.getStyleElement()}
          {styledComponentSheet.getStyleElement()}
        </React.Fragment>
      ),
    };
  } finally {
    styledComponentSheet.seal();
  }

};

export default MyDocument;
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start"
},
"dependencies": {
"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
"@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
"@date-io/moment": "1.x",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.7",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.47",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.6",
"@sambego/storybook-state": "^1.3.4",
"@sentry/browser": "^5.15.4",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-storysource": "^5.2.1",
"@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.2.1",
"@storybook/react": "^5.2.1",
"@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.3.2",
"@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
"airbnb-browser-shims": "^3.2.0",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
"babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
"babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^4.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2017-object-entries": "^0.0.5",
"core-js": "^2.6.5",
"dotenv-load": "^1.1.0",
"emoji-js": "^3.4.1",
"emoji-mart": "^2.11.1",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.9.1",
"es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
"formik": "^2.1.4",
"fuse.js": "^3.4.4",
"google-map-react": "^1.1.4",
"google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
"highcharts": "^7.1.2",
"highcharts-react-official": "^2.2.2",
"isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
"js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"material-table": "^1.57.2",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-countdown": "^0.0.3",
"next": "9.4.4",
"next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
"next-cookies": "^1.1.2",
"next-env": "^1.1.0",
"next-i18n-rewrites": "^0.0.7",
"next-i18next": "6.0.2",
"next-images": "^1.2.0",
"next-redux-saga": "^4.0.1",
"next-redux-wrapper": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
"next-routes": "^1.4.2",
"next-seo": "^1.2.0",
"next-transpile-modules": "^3.0.0",
"nprogress": "^0.2.0",
"polished": "^3.0.3",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"qs": "^6.9.0",
"rc-slider": "^8.6.11",
"rc-time-picker": "^3.7.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-confirm-alert": "^2.4.1",
"react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
"react-dates": "^20.1.0",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-ga": "^2.6.0",
"react-grid-system": "^4.4.3",
"react-height": "^3.0.1",
"react-inlinesvg": "^0.8.4",
"react-items-carousel": "^2.8.0",
"react-lazyload": "^2.5.0",
"react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.50",
"react-sortable-hoc": "^1.9.1",
"react-star-rating-component": "^1.4.1",
"react-stripe-elements": "^4.0.1",
"react-swipeable": "^5.2.2",
"react-toastify": "^5.1.0",
"react-tooltip": "^3.11.2",
"react-with-direction": "^1.3.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
"redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
"redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
"reduxsauce": "^1.0.1",
"reselect": "^4.0.0",
"styled-components": "4.1.3",
"webpack": "^4.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.8.7",
"@svgr/webpack": "^5.3.0",
"autoprefixer": "^9.3.1",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
"babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
"babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^4.0.0",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2017-object-entries": "^0.0.5",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
"babel-preset-airbnb": "^4.0.1",
"concurrently": "^4.1.0",
"eslint": "^5.16.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.0",
"jest": "^24.1.0",
"postcss-initial": "^3.0.0",
"postcss-preset-env": "^6.4.0",
"prettier": "1.16.4"
}
```

Comment: That's a crazy amount of dependencies. Do you need all of that? Seems like that's likely what's making your site so slow. Your bundle size must be gigantic. Can you verify how large it is?